# Yii2 Updating Table with Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii, yii2

I have created a JS script and Controller Action to Update a field upon click of a button as per the below.

I get the Success response but the table is not updated.

```
    public function actionSetstarttime()
    {
    
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $mySaveId =  $data['save_id'];

        $timeRecord = teammembers::find()
            ->where(['=', 'id', $mySaveId]) 
            ->one();
        $timeRecord->time_start =  12345;
        //Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime('now', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $timeRecord->save(false);

        return $timeRecord->time_start;
    }
 } // }}}
```

The JS in view is:

```
$('._starttime').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.fn.timer.worker.go();
    var first = $("#timeslot_id").val();

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/site/time",
            data: 'save_id='+first,
            success: function (data) {
               //do something
                console.log(data);
               alert("working");
            },
            error: function (exception) {
                console.log(exception);

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should send data as string JSON, not URL style string. If that does not solve the problem, post your routes and formatter configuration, the error could be there as well. Check the debug logs to see if `actionSetstartTime is being called`

Comment: `teammembers::find()->where(['=', 'id', $mySaveId])->one()` Can also be written as `TeamMebers::findOne($mySaveId);` same result but easier to read.

Comment: read about pjax in yii2 and use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your controller is SiteController.php Your url  is wrong. Based on your action you should use

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/site/setstarttime",
         .....
```